# How to create thumbnails using opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to downsample my image(using `anti-aliasing`) using `Python-Pillow's im.thumbnail()` method.

My code looks like:

```
MAXSIZE = 1024
im.thumbnail(MAXSIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Can you tell me some alternative in `opencv-python` to perform this re-sizing operation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cv2.resize . Documentation here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

In your case, assuming the input image im is a numpy array:

```
maxsize = (1024,1024) 
imRes = cv2.resize(im,maxsize,interpolation=cv2.CV_INTER_AREA)
```

There are different types of interpolation available (INTER_CUBIC, INTER_NEAREST, INTER_AREA,...) but according to the documentation if you need to shrink the image, you should get better results with CV_INTER_AREA.

Comment: cv2.resize will resize the image you provide to the specified dimensions.. maxsize is not the maximum size, it's the *target* size.

You can use the python library imutils.resize (opencv convenience functions). It wraps the cv2.resize function so that it will maintain the image aspect ratio when you resize, however it will also enlarge an image if the image you provide is smaller than the size you provide. To fix that, only call it if the image is larger.

Answer (score 1):

I got error:
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_INTER_AREA'

Following is worked for me:

```
imRes = cv2.resize(im,maxsize,interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).